# Was R2-D2 in Star Trek Beyond?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-beyond

In the previous two Star Trek movies, everyone’s favorite astromech(just barely edging out Skippy, the Jedi droid), makes a cameo as random junk. Did he manage to sneak about another Federation ship in Beyond?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### No

There is no recorded instance of R2-D2 appearing in *Star Trek: Beyond*. You can find a list of all easter eggs for that film [here](https://www.inverse.com/article/18618-star-trek-beyond-complete-easter-eggs).